# Codeigniter Image Resize with Big Images Not Working

Tags: image, codeigniter, resize

I've created a codeigniter website with a image resize function. This website worked great on my old webspace, now I transfered the website successfully to my new webspace, but unfortunately only small file size images are resized.
Big size images are not resized, and there are no errors displayed.

I've already checked the following stuff:
`memory_limit=64M`, `GD2` image library installed on server, `upload_max_filesize=25M`, `post_max_size=25M`, `max_input_time=300`, `max_execution_time=300`

Here's the resize code I use:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table1');

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $key => $row)
    {
    //$key value on error is '0'        
    $config_1['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';
    $config_1['source_image'] = $filePath . $fileName;
    $config_1['new_image'] = $filePath . 'resized1' . $fileExtension;
    $config_1['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config_1['width'] = 420;
    $config_1['height'] = 680;
    $config_1['quality'] = 100;
    //+ 2 other times the same for $config_2 and $config_3

    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config_1);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->clear();


    $this->image_lib->initialize($config_2);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->clear();
    //function quits here with big files (tested with 11 MB files)

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config_3);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->clear();
}
```

**//Update:** I've now tried to change image library to ImageMagick to see if it works. Now I get the following error (and images are not resized):

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: filesize(): stat failed for test-uploads/files/2016/02/01/resized-file.jpg

Filename: controllers/xyz.php

Line Number: xyz
```

The error occurs here:

```
$photo_size1 = filesize($filePath . $fileRename_1) / 1024;
```

Comment: [When an integer is used, the value is measured in bytes.](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

Comment: @Tpojka what do you mean with that?

Comment: I linked PHP docs in comment above. Maybe server php settings accept too small files only. Seems it is set to 25 bytes only. Try to change it to `3M` instead `25` for example and see what happens. Also change it for both: `upload_max_filesize=4M` and `post_max_size=4M`. Limit size of uploaded files to 3 MB let's say. Read again link I posted and pay attention on related pages for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.

Comment: @Tpojka thx for the quick reply unfortunately I had a look into my php.ini file and there are already all numbers with M at the end so the problem seems not to come from there :/

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick extension installed to try your code with that instead GD2?

Comment: @Tpojka yes I've got ImageMagick installed on my server. I've changed it from `gd2` to `imagemagick` but the images are not resized and saved in my directory I've set in the $config :/

Comment: Edit question with code of failed config.

Comment: I've now added the extra code.

Comment: Check if source file exists, after assigning `$config_1` array values, make check with `exit(file_exists($filePath . $fileName) ? 'Does' : 'doesn\'t');`.

Comment: Edit: I've edited the code above. The error appears when trying to get the filesize of the resized image (which doesn' exist because ImageMagick doesn't resize the images as well > and not even smaller sized images).

Comment: After first error occurance (you are using 3 processes) put `exit($this->image_lib->diplay_errors());` and see what errors you have.

Comment: Unfortunately already tried this and didn't get any errors at all :/

Comment: I've now found out that the `$key` in my `foreach` also stays at `0` (either when I use `ImageMagick` then for all images or if i use `GD2` then for every big images).

Code:
`foreach ($query->result_array() as $key => $row)`

Comment: It is hard to see in this fragmented snippets of code. We don't see half of code you claim error messages come from (`foreach` loop...). Try to narrow code to exact root of problem (i.e. work with simplified version of code such is one resize process etc).

Comment: Code snippet in question is now updatet with a simplified code in the full excerpt of the function.

Comment: In `foreach` loop you should do something with `$row` variable (i.e. `$row['filePath']`) maybe? I am not sure without seeing structure of `$query->result_array()`.

Comment: Yes, I use the '$row[''] in the loop but this has bothing todo withe the error (that's the reason because I left it out ok the code snippet in the question

Comment: Sorry, that way without responsive info or concrete code that produces error I am blind to help. You are seeing something in code, but rest of us do not. Please read [this article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and help other to help you.